# Swift - How to set a click event on a UIStackview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, stackview

I am trying to set a click event on my UIStackview to open a viewcontroller. When I do this nothing happens. It doesn't even print the line when I tap it. I tried multiple solutions on this website, like UITapGestureRecognizer but to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

My code:

```
private let stackUIView: UIView = {
     let stackUIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 25, y: 25, width: 400, height: 90))
    let tap = UIGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(stackviewClicked))
    stackUIView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    stackUIView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    
    return stackUIView
}()


@objc
    func stackviewClicked() {
        print("UIView Clicked")
        let testVC = testViewController()
        navigationController?.pushViewController(testVC, animated: true)

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

It should be `UITapGestureRecognizer` not `UIGestureRecognizer`

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(stackviewClicked))
```

Comment: Like I said in my post, I already tried that and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For me works, thanks

```
termsAndConditionsStack.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(stackviewClicked)))

@objc func stackviewClicked() {
     print("works")
}
```